# Python, filter queryset and set equal to zero if empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I'm using the following code to filter my queryset:

```
liquidity[element][0] = float(StatoPatrimoniale.objects.filter(reference_date__year=last_account_year).values_list('cassa')[0][0])
```

But If the queryset does not exist, python give me error. So I want to add the best solution to set

```
 liquidity[element][0]= 0
```

if the queryset filter is empty.

What is it the best solution?

Comment: What error? I hope you could just use *try...catch* clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    liquidity[element][0] = float(StatoPatrimoniale.objects.filter(reference_date__year=last_account_year).values_list('cassa')[0][0])                        
except StatoPatrimoniale.DoesNotExist:
    liquidity[element][0] = 0
```